# How to delete commit messages in GIT without losing any changes in local repository and push the same to remote repository?

Tags: git, github

I have 10 commit on remote and local main branch(they are in sync). Now I want to combine these commits into 1 or 2 commits in my local repository and push the same changes into remote repository(Github).

**Local & Remote**

```
Hashcode | Commit Message
------------------------
commit10 basic html page
commit9 add style <H1> tag with red color
commit8 add write hello world in <h1> tag 
commit7 add <h1> tag
commit6 add <p> tag
commit5 add bgcolor
commit4 add <body> tag
commit3 add <title> tag
commit2 add <html> tag
commit1 add index.html
```

As you can see the commits from commit2 to commit9 are not that helpful. It could have been done in a single commit. How do i keep the changes made by these commits but delete the commit messages so that the remote repository is not cluttered with unnecessary commit messages.

I have tried `git reset commit1` then `git add index.html` after that `git commit -m "basic html page"`

Required result after pushing the changes to remote repository

**Local & Remote**

```
commit2 add basic html page
commit1 add index.html
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called commit squashing. Example to squash the last 9 commits:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~9 // go back 9 commits
git add index.html
git commit -m "add basic html page"
```

You will find more information in this question:
[Squash my last X commits together using Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189560/squash-my-last-x-commits-together-using-git)